# PL/SQL - putting line while records are both found and not found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write small PL/SQL block which runs a tiny query inside. Problem is that I don't want to see whole data returned by query but to see whether something exists or not. My block looks like this:

```
procedure check_data as
table_data varchar2;
BEGIN
      SELECT * into table_data FROM  (
     with temp_table  as ( select   a_number, a_group, a_date from table1
                     where    a_id in (15)
                     )
       SELECT b_city, b_district, b_nationality, b_age
         FROM table2 JOIN temp_table ON a_id=b_id 
        WHERE b_age>=10
        and b_age<23
                ORDER BY b_nationality DESC);

  IF SQL%FOUND THEN 
                raise_application_error(-20001,'OK, found something')
  else DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('found nothing!');
  end if;
  end;
```

Generally struggling with declaring temp_table (I get PLS-00201: identifier 'table_data' must be declared) and putting results on screen.

I'll be grateful for any tips.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434437/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-record-exists-in-oracle

Comment: @mc88. Please make sure that you post the table DDL as well when you wants someone to work on your not working code.

Comment: what structure of table_data ? what you want if query exists - select into something ?

Comment: @Rene. I didnot check his logic or whole code. I found one mistake and corrected it and asked him to try. you must not downvote unnecessarily. If you know better then you can post the complete solution rather that just posting the link

Comment: @Rene.Also Op is looking for a solution to his problem in PL SQL block not in your way using a sql.

Comment: @Raj_Te - you can use those approaches to select into a variable in PL/SQL, and then test its value.

Comment: so many issues with that code... must learn the basics.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole. As said earlier, i just checked the error which OP was facing and resolved it. He didnot asked for alternative solutions so no point giving it. He wanted to get it done via PLSQL block and in his own way and encountered an issue which i resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this now:

```
create  table table1( a_id number,a_number number, a_group varchar(10), a_date date) 

create table table2 (b_id number,b_city varchar(10), b_district varchar(10), b_nationality varchar(10), b_age number)

create or replace procedure check_data as
table_data varchar2(100);
BEGIN
      SELECT * 
      into table_data 
      FROM  (
      with temp_table  as ( select  a_id, a_number, a_group, a_date 
                            from  table1
                          where    a_id in (15)
                     )
       SELECT 1
         FROM table2 
       JOIN temp_table ON a_id = b_id 
        WHERE b_age>=10
        and b_age<23       
        ORDER BY b_nationality DESC)
       where  rownum < 2 ;

    IF SQL%FOUND THEN 
       raise_application_error(-20001,'OK, found something');
    Else 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('found nothing!');
    End if;
  end;
```

Its working fine and compiled well. Now implement the expert suggestion to get it working fine. I am not looking into your logic. I just get your code compiled.