# How to efficiently and clearly check for existence of a row in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle19c

Assume you have some large table `foo` that contains a column  `bar` which has a relatively low number of values. For example, 10,000 rows where the `bar` column can contain just `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`.

What is the fastest *and clearest* way to check for the existence of a single row where the `foo` column contains an `'a'` value, without causing Oracle to scan every row and instead short-circuit once it has located 1 matching row?

This way is fast and concise, but I don't think it is immediately clear from the use of `rownum` that your goal is to check existence as quickly as possible:

```
select count(1)
from foo
where bar = 'a' and rownum = 1;
```

This way is fast and more clear/obvious to me than the use of `rownum` but I still don't think it is immediately obvious, imo.

```
select count(1)
from dual
where exists (
    select 1
    from foo
    where bar = 'a'
)
```

Is there a standard, idiomatic way to check existence for a row in Oracle that is both fast and clear as to the intent of the query?

Comment: There are many, many ways of writing it (including these [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=802bcfc5ad1f22fcd006e9cb97e8254d)) and it is personal opinion which one you use.

Comment: Similar to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434437/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-record-exists-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

Your second version is obviously wrong - you can't select from a column (as you are, in the subquery).

The first version is perfectly fine (and efficient) - the `rownum = 1` condition causes short-circuiting. It may not be immediately clear what the purpose of the `rownum` condition is; if that is a concern, include a comment to explain it. The query will return 1 as soon as the value of interest is first found in the column. (The table is still full-scanned, of course, if the value is not present; then the query will return 0.)

If you need an even faster check, you would need an index on column `bar`; the query may still be the same, but the runtime will scan the index rather than the table.

Comment: Nothing to add.

Comment: I've edited the error in the second version.